# Auto-Insert Rows when Data is entered & then merge cells

Tags: vba, excel

When data is entered (user has hit "return") into any cell in Column B, I want to insert four rows directly below the row that just had data entered into it.

I want the program to run automatically after the user has hit return on the cell. I've been having three sticking points:

1. Finding a way for the program to run without the user having to hit a button. I've spent a fair amount of time searching for example code to use and have found several resources, but the two examples I've used haven't seemed to work. PDCA is the sheet name, Add_Row is the macro I've written to add rows below the user-inputted data.

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(Target, [B3:B14]) Is Nothing Then Sheets("PDCA Tracking").Add_Row
End Sub`

2. Actually running the Add_Row program. I get an Error 1004 Application Defined or User Defined Error. My second question is, when the user hits return, the active cell wouldn't be the one s/he just entered data in then, would it? How would I mitigate that? It would be the last row of the spreadsheet, could I find the last row and then just add rows below that?:

   ```
        Sub Add_Row'Insert row below active cell
   ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
       Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(1), 3).Value = "Zulu"
   ActiveCell.Offset(2).EntireRow.Insert
       Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(2), 3).Value = "Yankee"
   ActiveCell.Offset(3).EntireRow.Insert
       Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(3), 3).Value = "X-Ray"
   ActiveCell.Offset(4).EntireRow.Insert
       Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(4), 3).Value = "Whiskey"

   'Call Merge_Cells
   End Sub
   ```
3. After I enter the data, I want to take the cells below the row where the user just added the data and merge them. (ie if the user input "banana" and I added four rows below "banana", I want JUST the four new cells under banana to merge with the cell containing "banana". I know there's a .Merge command but again, not sure of the syntax to use.

Any and all help is very appreciated!

UPDATE: I figured out how to add data below the last filled in row, I believe.

```
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = "Zulu"
Cells(lastRow + 2, 3).Value = "Yankee"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo haveError

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And _
       Not Application.Intersect(Target, [B3:B14]) Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Target
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(4, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            .Resize(5, 1).Merge
            .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
    Exit Sub

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I lied, I saved it specifically to the sheet and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One more question. I added an InputBox to see if the user wanted me to insert rows (see code below) `Answer = InputBox("Will this event trigger the events? (Y/N)") If Answer = "Y" Then With Target .Offset(1, 0).Resize(4, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown .Offset(0, 1).Value = "Zulu" .Offset(1, 1).Value = "Yankee" .Resize(4, 1).Merge .VerticalAlignment = xlTop End With Application.EnableEvents = True End If`but if I answer N, the next cell that I edit data in doesn't ask me the same question. Thoughts?

Comment: You're only re-enabling events if the user answers Yes.

Comment: Gotcha thanks, fixed it. That was a silly mistake on my part.